# Can I modify email headers in an IMAP folder?

Tags: email, imap

My email provider anti-spam system adds a tag before the subject of emails when it detects spam or viruses.

It looks like `*** PROBABLY SPAM *** What a night we had !`

It's not very accurate and results in many false positive tags.

I archive some emails (like the one in the example) and these tags look dirty.

Do you know a way to get rid of them occasionally, without disabling the filter on the server ?

Thank you,
Stéphane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, but you can download the messages, process them, and upload them back to IMAP folders. Any good IMAP client will let you do that.

Comment: Which imap client? I do not know anyone which is able to process messages without sending them again. Thanks.

Comment: @Toc: "that" meaning "download the messages, process them, and upload them back".